# Multiple iterated varied input elements using jquery

Tags: c#, jquery

I am using MVC3 razor with the following markup:

```
<div class="budget">
<!--line item-->
<div class="budget-row">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="twelve columns">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="two mobile-one columns">
                <label class="right inline">Item:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="ten mobile-three columns">
                @Html.TextBox("description[]", "", new { @class = "expand" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="two mobile-one columns">
                <label class="right inline">Cost:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="two mobile-one columns field-left">
                @Html.TextBox("amount[]", "0", new { @class = "expand" })
                </div>
                <div class="one mobile-one columns">
                <label class="right inline">Markup:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="one mobile-one columns field-left">
                @Html.TextBox("markup_amount[]", "0", new { @class = "expand" })
                </div>
                <div class="one mobile-one columns field-left">
                <select id="markup_type[]" style="display:none;">
                <option value="P" SELECTED>%</option>
                <option value="D">$</option>
                </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!--row-->    
</div>
<!--end line item-->

    <a class="button radius small success middle" href="#" id="submit">Submit</a>
</div>
```

The "budget" div is the overall div, the "budget-row" div can be one or multiple lines.  I am looking for an iteration catching values of each input.  I have tried this:

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
    $(".budget input[type=text]").each(function() {
        alert(this.value);
    });
    return false;
});
```

Frankly, tried so many things, that might not be even close at this point. And that only returns my text boxes, as well.

Thanks

Edit
This is adding the output code:

```
<div class="budget">
<!--line item-->
<div class="budget-row">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="twelve columns">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="two mobile-one columns">
                    <label class="right inline">Item:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="ten mobile-three columns">
                    <input class="expand" id="description__" name="description[]" type="text" value="" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="two mobile-one columns">
                    <label class="right inline">Cost:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="two mobile-one columns field-left">
                    <input class="expand" id="amount__" name="amount[]" type="text" value="0" />
                </div>
                <div class="one mobile-one columns">
                    <label class="right inline">Markup:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="one mobile-one columns field-left">
                    <input class="expand" id="markup_amount__" name="markup_amount[]" type="text" value="0" />
                </div>
                <div class="one mobile-one columns field-left">
                    <select id="markup_type[]" style="display:none;">
                        <option value="P" SELECTED>%</option>
                        <option value="D">$</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!--row-->    
</div>
<!--end line item-->

<a class="button radius small success middle" href="#" id="submit">Submit</a>
</div>
```

Comment: alert($(this).val());

Comment: The alert is returning the value OK - I could certainly update the syntax - but how do I also get the select?

Comment: I could be wrong but I can't see any `<input type="text"/>` fields anywhere in the above question? or is that what the `@Html.TextBox("markup_amount[]", "0", new { @class = "expand" })` does?

Comment: Please show us the actual generated HTML that the browser sees (you can get it from View/Source in your browser), not the server-side template.  For example, there no `@Html.TextBox()` in HTML.  We need to see what that becomes in the actual HTML of the page because it's the actual HTML that the jQuery must interact with.

Comment: Correct, that is ASP.NET Razor syntax; I will be populating for edits, so would like to maintain.

Comment: Updated to include output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with for getting your selected value. Not sure if this was all you were needing, or if there was more.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="two mobile-one columns">
        <label class="right inline">Cost:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="two mobile-one columns field-left">
        <input type="text" value="1" class="first" />
    </div>
    <div class="one mobile-one columns">
        <label class="right inline">Markup:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="one mobile-one columns field-left">
        <input type="text" value="2" class="second" />
    </div>
    <div class="one mobile-one columns field-left">
        <select id="markup_type[]" class="first">
            <option value="A" SELECTED>%</option>
            <option value="B">$</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="one mobile-one columns field-left">
        <select id="test_type[]" class="second">
            <option value="Z" SELECTED>%</option>
            <option value="Y">$</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#submit").click(function () {
        $("select :selected").each(function(){
            alert($(this).val());
            //get the corresponding input for this select
            var cName = $(this).parent().attr("class");
            var div = $(this).closest(".row");
            var input = $("." + cName, div);
            alert($(input).val());
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

You can check out the [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/HUegP/33/).

Notice that we are tying a select to an input using a class. In this example I've marked the input with class="first" and the select with class="first" to tie them together.

Let me know if this works for you or not.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  My only issue is if I have iterated rows, as mentioned, how do I clearly associate the text inputs with the selects?  If I run your fiddle with 2 iterations of the fields, I get 1, 2, 1, 2, P, P.  Does that make sense?

Comment: I see. you'll need something slightly different for that. Let me see what I can do.

Comment: Updated, not happy with parent().parent().parent() so going to see if there's a better way. I sure hope so...

Comment: Mike, do you think there is anyway to get the values based on the input/select ids?  For example, there are 2 things: one, if I had multiple selects, this would iterate the 2 inputs twice; second, would it be consistent how the fields returned?  i.e. the cost always returns first, then the markup, etc.  And not sure how I would catch those to assign to the right variable...something like running a counter or something?  Thanks for the time!

Comment: This will not iterate the inputs twice actually. CHeck out the updated fiddle. I'll add an explanation of what it is doing.

Comment: Hi Mike, I did a quick update to the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HUegP/22/  When there are 2 selects, it does iterate the inputs twice.  Something I can do to prevent that?

Comment: i see, in the prev example I thought there was only 1 select per section. Let me see.